# AWS CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-code-deploy

My app is created using `elastic-beanstalk` aws service, do I need to use the AWS CodeDeploy service to deploy my app?

Currently I just do:

```
eb deploy myApp
```

Then, a new application version is deployed without using AWS CodeDeploy. 
So, AM I doing something wrong?

Comment: https://youtu.be/TSnlRNuKQ-s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elastic beanstalk do it on your behalf. During deployment process you define some polices and roles, which defines elastic beanstalk will call these services on your behalf. Codedeploy is one of that services. 
Elasticbeanstalk does automation of your process only and setup thet whole deployment environment for you (php,nginx/apache in case of web), if you look /opt/elasticbeanstalk/, you can see codedeploy folder there, which means that you do not need to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

AWS code deploy is different workaround and provides more controlling. How you want your changes to be pushed, is it to be pushed on all instances an once or one by one, minimum number of healthy instances.

Check here-

http://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-deploy-application-code-from-s3-using-aws-codedeploy/

http://blog.powerupcloud.com/2016/03/24/deployment-automation-using-aws-code-depoly/

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx33XKAKURCCW83/Automatically-Deploy-from-GitHub-Using-AWS-CodeDeploy

Answer (score 0):

You can update the your application with new version. CLI as follows
$eb deploy --version

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. EB Deploy will enable you to deploy your apps being served from Elastic Beanstalk. AWS Code Deploy on the other hand is more flexible & gives you more control, you can for example, deploy apps you are serving from EC2 thats not being managed by Elastic Beanstalk.

With AWS you can for example deploy to multiple environments ie development, staging, production.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk and CodeDeploy are totally different AWS services and independent of each other and follow different deployment approaches.

What you're doing is totally correct to deploy a new version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

AWS elastic-bean-stalk itself has the nice capability for deploying applications nicely.You dont need to use aws code deploy again.It will be superflous.You can use beanstalk tools itself to deploy the code.

Answer (score -5):

AWS CodeDeploy is a building block service focused on helping developers deploy and update software on any instance, including Amazon EC2 instances and instances running on-premises. 
AWS Elastic Beanstalk (as well as AWS OpsWorks btw) are end-to-end application management solutions.
When it comes to deploying new software release on Beanstalk, you better use the own deployment process provided to you by Beanstalk.

```
eb deploy myApp
```